# What am i missing over this sql request?

Tags: mysql, jquery-autocomplete

databases loaded of course. The get term is an autocomplete tring, which can be found in the database under groupname, but as you see, if it is not a match, i don't want to run the first part of if, if found, yes. The problem is, if I replace the get term part for the actual string, it works, and if i add a string that is not present in the database, it still works like charm. But when get term is done, it doesnt matter if the string can be found or not, numrows will be larger than 0 anyway. Why? = and LIKE tried as well ofc

```
$query = "select * from `gamegroups` where `groupname` = '%{$_GET['term']}%'";

$resultset = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultset) > 0 ){

$lolz = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $lolz[] = $row['gameid'];
}
echo json_encode($lolz);
            }else{print "no match debug";}
?>
```

Comment: The first thing you're missing is the step where you sanitize your inputs.  This is *wide open* to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the actual query text at runtime that gets executed against the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query =  "select * from gamegroups where groupname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%' LIMIT 1";
```

Because of the wildcard, I assume you want a like result?

**What you really want is to make a relevance score, and return results ordered by relevance, but that is outside the scope of this question.**

Comment: Your statement will return an error, the = sign is missing between the $query variable and the query string.

Comment: fixed. Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: The data is an autocomplete string, which is fairly simple, like your name. If the php we're looking at finds a match in the sql database, it will run the if, if it cannot be found, then the numrows result should not be larger than 0, that's my issue. The problem is somewhere within the get term phase, becuase regardless if the database search is successful or not, it finds "something". If i replace et term with actual "nametobesearchedbyautocomplete" than numrows work okay, even if it's a match or not.

Comment: Oh boy... I'll try to debug it somehow then, thanks everyone! I'll check back regularly in the next 2 hours if You may find something.

Comment: Holy crap :) the term was name in my clientside code, thanks everything!